# asp.net character encoding problem utf8

Tags: c#, asp.net, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm storing some html-encoded data in a sql server database and I've written a script to output the data in a csv format minus the html tags and I'm getting a weird issue when html-decoding the remaining data.  For example the data contains a quote character (which is html-encoded as `&#8217;`),  but when I try to html-decode it the data comes out as a series of weird characters (â€™).  Does anyone know how to solve this issue?  The output encoding of the page is UTF-8 if that helps.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Cheers

Tim

Comment: Have you actually specified UTF-8 in the page?

Comment: Yes I've added the ResponseEncoding="UTF-8" attribute to the page

Comment: I've actually just found that the characters display fine in notepad but Excel 2000 seems to be replacing the chars with other weird characters!

Answer (score 3):

Those 3 weird characters are [how UTF-8 encodes the HTML entity `&#8217;`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm).  (They're actually the octets `0xE2 0x80 0x99`, and those bytes render as "â€™" in your computer's default charset `windows-1252`.)  So I don't think you've got an issue with your encoding.

It's evidently a known problem that Excel 2000 has problems with .csv files in UTF-8 encoding.  The solution, bizarrely enough, is to [switch the filename extension to .txt](http://unicode.org/mail-arch/unicode-ml/Archives-Old/UML024/0705.html), at which point Excel 2000 will evidently import the file correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is read from the CSV files, open the csv file in notepad  press Save As in the fiile menu, save the file as Encoding-UTF8.